# KubernetesExecutor + PythonOperator + AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DAGS_IN_IMAGE is sending in sub directory command causing pods to not start properly

Tags: airflow

When using KubernetesExecutor and creating tasks using PythonOperator, when the pods are created they are searching for a dag in a folder that doesn't exist. I noticed in the scheduler logs that the task is being sent the -sd argument but I don't know why.
Add task `('blah', 'scoring_tasks', datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 30, 22, 46, 54, 146783, tzinfo=<TimezoneInfo [UTC, GMT, +00:00:00, STD]>), 1)` with command

```
['airflow', 'run', 'dag_example', 'score_task', '2020-11-30T22:46:54.146783+00:00', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '-sd', '/src/blah/blah']
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

What happened was i was using wrong image in executorConfig

Comment: Could you please provide your dag example. Thanks in advance. It will be great help